# How to replace the "KeyboardInterrupt" command for another key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboardinterrupt

I have the following code:

```
while True:
    try:
        #DoSomething
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

But instead of using <kbd>Crtl + C</kbd>, I want to type another key to end the loop. How can I do this?

Comment: Inside the loop you'll need to check if a key has been pressed, and if so, get it and see if it's the one that stops the loop. Checking for keypresses is OS-depend, although there are some third-party modules that work on several platforms that can do that (and more).

Comment: Here's one of them named [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) and another named [`pynput`](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/).

Comment: `Ctrl+C` is standard method to stop script in system and it is processed by system - for other keys you have to use some module to check pressed keys and `raise KeyboardInterrupt` or use `while running` and set `running = False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `keyboard` module:

```py
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("some key"):
        break

    do_something()
```

This will keep doing something until `some key` is pressed. Then, it will break out of the endless loop.

To catch hotkeys, use the `add_hotkey` function:

```py
import keyboard


def handle_keypress(key):
    global running

    running = False
    print(key + " was pressed!")


running = True
keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+e", lambda: handle_keypress("Ctrl-E"))

while running:
    do_something()
```

Or you can use `pynput`:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Listener


def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))


with Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:

    listener.join()
```

Comment: About "keyboard", these's an Erorr when you're not root: ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of using that [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module  I mentioned in my second comment. It handles most of steps I mentioned in my first comment and works on several platforms. The loop will stop if and when the user presses the <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> key.

Note that <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> will still raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep

def callback(keyname):
    global stopped
    print(f'{keyname} was pressed!')
    stopped = True

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+b', lambda: callback('Ctrl-B'))

stopped = False
print('Doing something...')
while not stopped:
    sleep(1)  # Something

print('-fini-')
```